# Python Pexpect full output is not saved (How to deal with the "--More--" prompt?)

Tags: python, python-2.7, stdout, pexpect

I am using Pexpect to run a command remotely on a server and saving the output in a file. However, it does not save the whole output as it's truncated due to `--More--` . Is there a way to avoid `--More--`, so that the whole output is saved  in the output file?

I have tried using `child.setwinsize(1000,1000)` but it didn't solve the issue.

Current code:

```
import pexpect
import time

child = pexpect.spawn('ssh username@ip_address')
time.sleep(1)

child.sendline('password')
time.sleep(1)

child.logfile = open("output.txt", "w")
child.sendline('command')
child.expect(pexpect.EOF)

print child.before, child.after
child.close
```

Comment: Can you share the command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what command you're running but usually you can press <kbd>SPACE</kbd> when you see the `--More--` prompt. For example:

```
import pexpect, sys

child = pexpect.spawn('more /etc/services')
child.logfile_read = sys.stdout

patterns = ['--More--', pexpect.EOF]
while True:
    ret = child.expect(patterns)
    if ret == 0:
        child.send(' ')
    elif ret == 1:
        break
```

Comment: give it a try please.

Comment: It solved for me too....but along with that the output shows spaces given..something like...`^[[7m--More--^[[27m^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H        ^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H`.....I will be thankful if any solution for this..

Comment: @YogeshJilhawar - there's no easy solution for that. u need to handle that by your self.

Comment: good to know u find a solution. i know nothing about the specific dev commands u r using. :)

Answer (score 2):

I found one more answer-  just execute below command before actual command.

```
terminal length 0
```

After that suppose I entered some command like `show ip interface`.  Then, This will show whole output. You don't need to press enter again and again. As,

```
child.sendline('terminal length 0')   
child.expect('# ')    
child.sendline('show ip interface')   #write your command here
child.expect('# ')
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. For my switch I needed to use the command `terminal datadump`.